# trying to run module, but this syntax error pops up

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scripting

> the error its throwing off.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\castl\Desktop\New folder (2)\acc-python-master\Proj05\Proj05.py", line 1, in <module>
import Proj05Runner
File "C:\Users\castl\Desktop\New folder (2)\acc-python-master\Proj05\Proj05Runner.py", line 13
   else:
      ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

> heres my driver code.

```
import Proj05Runner

str = 'The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence.'
subStr = 'fox'
result = Proj05Runner.run(str,subStr)
print(result)
```

> Here the module thats supposed to work with the driver.

```
def run(str, subStr):
    """Returns a substring of any given string based upon a given range of characters before and after the substring"""

    str_range = 3

    if subStr in str:
        str_modified = str[str.index(subStr) - str_range : str.index(subStr) + len(subStr) + str_range]
        return "I certify that this program is my own work " + "\n" + str + "\n" + subStr + "\n" + str_modified
    "and is not the work of others. I agree not " + "\n" + str + "\n" + subStr + "\n" + str_modified
    "to share my solution with others. " + "\n" + str + "\n" + subStr + "\n" + str_modified
    "Print your name here." + "\n" + str + "\n" + subStr + "\n" + str_modified
                
    else:
        return "ERROR: subStr not found in str!"
```

im sorry, still kinda new too python scripting. so any help will be great.

Comment: This looks like an indentation issue: Try to indent the three string lines ("and ....", "to share ...", and "Print your ..."). Though I don't think the code is doing what you intended to do.

Comment: You forgot the `+` after each non-final use of  `str_modified` in the expression being returned.

Answer (score 1):

Does this code do what you expected?

**Code:**

```py
def run(str, subStr):
    """Returns a substring of any given string based upon a given range of characters before and after the substring"""

    str_range = 3

    if subStr in str:
        str_modified = str[str.index(subStr) - str_range : str.index(subStr) + len(subStr) + str_range]
        return ("I certify that this program is my own work " + "\n" + str + "\n" + subStr + "\n" + str_modified +
                "and is not the work of others. I agree not " + "\n" + str + "\n" + subStr + "\n" + str_modified +
                "to share my solution with others. " + "\n" + str + "\n" + subStr + "\n" + str_modified +
                "Print your name here." + "\n" + str + "\n" + subStr + "\n" + str_modified)
    else:
        return "ERROR: subStr not found in str!"
```

Note the indentation of the three additional string lines, the parenthesis, as well as the "+" at the end of each line.